# Windows Phone webbrowser retrieve cookie

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, cookies, windows-phone-8

i.What I'm trying to do here is to let the user sign in his account in a webpage w/ webbrowser control.

ii.Then retrieve the cookie from it.

iii.Every time webpage loaded w/ this cookie will include a unique securitytoken in the page.

iv.I want to retrieve the securitytoken in order to make a http post request

I have already figured out the 3rd and 4th part. But I don't know how to get the cookie from webbrowser control.

I've read dozens of posts still can't get a clear idea to achieve this function.

Thank you guys in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Referring to MSDN Doc: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dd920298(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dd920298%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Assuming you have response as `HttpWebResponse response`

```
foreach (Cookie cookieValue in response.Cookies)
{
  //cookieValue.ToString()
}
```